# Simple jQuery: Why does this not work?

Tags: jquery, input

The value is always undefined (Chrome 12.0.742.112). 
The .get() does return an HTML input object but accessing value is undefined.

```
<input id="a" value="abc" onkeyup="b()" />
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>

function b() {
    alert($('#a').get().value);
}

</script>
```

However using standard JS works (as does .val()):

```
document.getElementById('a').value      // this works
$('#a').val()                           // as does this
```

Comment: Did you do `alert($('#a').get())`? ;) `alert` is not a debugging tool. `alert(1)` and `alert([1])` will give you the same output. Use `console.log` (`console.dir`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.get` without arguments returns an array. You can pass in `0` to get the first element.

Use

```
alert($('#a').get(0).value);
```

Answer (score 0):

get Retrieve the DOM elements matched by the jQuery object.

Try http://jsfiddle.net/2924C/8/